# Flutter image does not fit in

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```
Container(
  width:
  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4.4,
  height:
  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 10,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
        color: Colors.black12,
        width: 1.5,
        style: BorderStyle.solid),
    borderRadius:
    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
  ),
  child: (TmpBytesImage == null)
      ? Icon(Icons.camera_alt,
      color: Colors.black26)
      : Image.memory(TmpBytesImage,
      fit: BoxFit.fill),
),
```

I expected was to fill `Container` with images.

but image looks like ignore `BoxDecoration`

[image]

How to get image to look like this `Container`?

Comment: Do let me know if it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

---

Simply use `Card`, give it `shape` and put your `Container` inside it. Simple example:

```
Card(
  elevation: 12,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
  ),
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
    child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
      child: Image.asset(
        chocolateImage,
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add the image inside the container decoration

like this

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image:
                              AssetImage('assets/image.jpg'),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
```

Comment: Congratulations, good answer!
But ...
Inform the file path, where the code mentioned in your answer must be inserted.
And approximately which line should be placed.